# Initializing View, Template and Controller and Model is optional

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, controller, initialization

> *I was too sleepy when I asked the question, so sorry for that, anyway to make things clear I prepared the question for 2 hours.*

I'm trying to organize my code and decided to organize it mvc'ish(mvc-like), I don't know if I can follow all the principles, but I wanted to be at least close to that.

My application has a front-controller (dunno if my definition is right), so that all the http-request of my application will be passing through a single point, in my case the `index.php` in the root directory of my application.

Having said that I have set it up like that, you can imagine that I used `.htaccess` to direct all request to `index.php`.

I exploded the `url` and created an array out of it, `$url[]` like so. So whenever I access my app like this `http://localhost/app/pagename` it'll be accessing a controller (`pagename_controller`)

I did it like this :

```
$file = $controller_path . $page . '_controller.php';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    require $file;
    $class_name = ucfirst($page) . '_controller';
    $target = new $class_name();
}
```

also I wrap it up in a Container, the 'decorator pattern', for future use, validations maybe.
like this :

```
$controller = new Wrap($target);
$controller->index();
```

I don't know if the use of `$controller` variable name is appropriate so please forgive me when it is all wrong.

I kinda think that I can setup my application like this :

1. user sends a request, how? by using the application means that he/she sends out a http-request, that will load the initial state of the application

   [image: credit : phparchitect design patterns]

As you can see in the diagram of my desired application structure, I was able to do only the first part which is to direct the request to a single entry (`index.php`)

Now the problems are the initialization of other parts of the application.

As of this moment, I have 3 files that I want to setup, but I am confused on how.

`index_controller`, `index_view`, `Template`

```
class Index_controller {
    private $model;
    private $view;

    public function __construct(){
        // optional model -> $this->model = 'index' 
        $this->view = 'index'  // 
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view($this->view)
    }
}

class Index_view {
    private $model;
    private $template;

    public function __construct(Model $model = null){
         $this->template = new Template('default');
    }

    public function view() {
         $this->template->assign('css', 'default_css'); // don't know if this is efficient
         // or $this->template->assign('header', 'default_header');
         // or $this->template->assign('sidebar', 'default_sidebar');
         // or $this->template->assign('footer', 'default_footer');
         // or any other things I want to use in the template
    }
}

class Template {

    public $data = array();
    private $tmpl;

    public function __construct($template) {
         $this->tmpl = $template . '_tmpl.php';
    }

    public function assign($name, $value){
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    // public function output
    // function that will explode the data array and render it out as a webpage
    // I'll create templates and
}
```

With that at hand, I want to know now how do I link those things together. At the moment I have a `system` folder that can contain classes, and I setup a autoloader for that folder.

I am thinking of creating a `Controller` class and `View` class that acts as the ActionFactory and ViewFactory as illustrated in the diagram, although I know that these are not their responsibilities.

I am thinking of this :

```
class Controller {

    protected $load;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load = new View();
    }
}

class View {
    public function __construct() {
    // some things i don't know
    }

    public function view() {
    // some things i don't know
    }
}
```

What are your suggestions and comments in my setup. How can I initiate the triad?

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is.  Can you please update your post to ask a set of specific questions?

Comment: Edited, I made it super clear and I tried it too

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito are you validating `$page`? If not, you have a local file inclusion vulnerability, `file_exists()` won't prevent that.

Comment: how do I validate it? i have a condition that if `$url[0]` is empty, use the `$config['default_controller']` as `$page` and if not empty `$page = $url[0]`. Any other things should i do?

Comment: Validate it so that it can only contain a-z0-9 or just a-z.

Comment: ah got that, I have filter_var, sanitize_url in my initialization of my `$url` so I think that will do

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's not get stuck on your implementation details too much. You can go read about securing your framework at some other time. Let's deal with your question...

I actually created a framework that works along the lines you are trying to implement. I think what you are missing is a RoutingHandler class. Routing is the physical manipulation of the URL, which tells your application which Controller to load, and which Action to run.

In my world I also have Modules, so the basic routing scheme is

```
Module -> Controller -> Action
```

These three items map to my URI scheme in that fashion. Variables can be appended also like so...

http://www.domain.com/module/controller/action/var1/val1/var2/val2

So, what happens after the URI is parsed, and control is passed over to the appropriate controller and action? Let's make some code up to demonstrate a simple example...

```
<?php    
    class indexController extends Controller {

        protected function Initialize() {
            $this->objHomeModel = new HomeModel;

            $this->objHeader = new Header();
            $this->objFooter = new Footer();

            $this->objHeader
                ->SetPageId('home');
        }

        public function indexAction() {
            $this->objHeader->SetPageTitle('This is my page title.');
        }
    }
?>
```

In the `Initialize` method, I'm setting some controller-wide stuff, and grabbing an instance of my Model to use later. The real meat is in the `indexAction` method. This is where you would set up stuff to use in your View. For example...

```
public function randomAction() {
    $this->_CONTROL->Append($intSomeVar, 42);
}
```

`_CONTROL` is an array of values that I manipulate and pass onto the View. The `Controller` class knows how to find the right template for the View because it is named after the Action (and in a sibling directory).

The `Controller` parent class takes the name of the action method and parses it like so...

```
indexAction -> index.tpl.php
```

You can also do some other fun stuff here, for example...

```
Application::SetNoRender();
```

...would tell the Controller not to render inside a template, but just complete the method. This is useful for those situations where you don't actually want to output anything.

Lastly, all of the controllers, models, and views live inside their own directory like so...

```
my_module
    controllers
        indexController.class.php
        someotherController.class.php
        :
        :
    models
        HomeModel.class.php
        :
        :
    templates
        index.tpl.php
        someother.tpl.php
        :
        :
```

I could go on, but I'm writing this from memory, and there are some wrinkles here and there, but hopefully this gives you food for thought.

Comment: Even though just an example, your `Initialise()` method is creating new objects left right an centre. Dependency Injection or education toward IoC principle is needed as a side-note here.

Comment: One word: "Singleton", baby!

Comment: I hope you mean "NEVER use Singletons". Or static methods for that matter ;)

Comment: You say that like you're "The Decider"... there are many approaches and opinions. If there were just one, this game would be Dullsville. Sure, Singletons are overused and often misunderstood, but they have a place. As do static methods when used sparingly. Sure, they are often used in place of well-thunk architecture, but I can't fix that.

Comment: Oh of course. No I'm not the decider, however I learn from those more knowledgeable than myself on such matters and then pass on that knowledge in the hope they'll do the same. Singletons have no place in PHP. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323), quite interesting. Statics make code untestable and hard to follow (also bad architecture) - but if you're stuck with this at your job, you have to go with the flow. Just know better for when you code for fun and profit yourself :)